# RC oscillator model in attiny microcontroller

Tags: avr, oscillator, atmel, attiny, oscillation

I was reading in the datasheet for the attiny85 that the internal RC oscillator can be callibrated to run at different frequencies based on the value in the OSCCAL register. (Page 194 graph: RC Oscillator Frequency vs. OSCCAL Value) I would like to learn more about how this type of oscillator works at a hardware level, so I was wondering if it could be ordered​ seperately from the attiny85 or if there is a similar one? Thanks!

Edit: If an exact model number isn't known, then some recommendations as to what to look for would be appreciated, too...

Comment: There are all manner of digitally commanded oscillators for sale today.  But have you considered just using an ATtiny?  Use one of the counters to output a fixed fraction of the system clock or the peripheral clock that is multiplied from it on a pin, then write an I2C slave program for it which will change the OSSCAL on command.

Comment: That's kinda my problem... There are a ton of rc oscillator on mouser. I have no idea which one to get. I'm just trying to learn, but that's harder to do without hardware. I want to understand like how that register is electrically connected to the RC oscillator in the microcontroller, lol... Not very practical, just curious.

Comment: An RC oscillator could be adjusted by any of changing the resistance, capacitance, or threshold voltage.  So it may switch resistors or capacitors into or out of the circuit or set a threshold of comparison.  The full scope of possibilities belong in textbooks and research papers - everyday tasks are more about choosing something from what is on the market that will meet a need, and data sheets or whitepapers may offer clues how it works.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll just try to pick one on my own then. Im trying to fill an order from mouser so that the shipping cost is less comparable to the actual cost of my order.. lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ATTINYs use **tunable RC oscillators**. These are like normal RC oscillators, but have extra parts that allow the frequency to be adjusted.

While I have never seen any documentation specifically on what strategy the ATTINYs use to allow the frequency to be adjusted (and it could be different from part to part), one possible way is to digitally add or remove resistors to the RC to change the frequency. The these resistors would be controlled by the OSSCAL register.

There are other ways to implement tunable RC oscillators too...
https://www.google.com/search?q=tunable+RC+oscillator&oq=tunable+RC+oscillator&aqs=chrome..69i57.158j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=digitally+tunable+RC+oscillator

Comment: Ok, thanks. You could probably do that with a transistor array connected directly to the OSCCAL bits, right? That's just a guess... How does a tunable RC oscillator differ from a programmable oscillator, like from Texas Instruments? Are they very different?

Comment: Yes, you could make something that worked like an ATTINY tunable RC with an array of transistors attached to an array of resistors. The gates of the transistors would be the "bits" of an OSSCAL register.

Comment: Again, we do not know anything documented about the ATTINY85 tunable RC oscillator's implementation, so  it is hard to compare it to others, but it is likely simpler, less accurate, and slower than any of the programmable oscillators I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know all Atmel microcontrollers I've encountered do have an internal oscillator. It cannot be separated from the chip as it's manufactured *with* an RC oscillator embedded in the chip. However you can just not-use it as soon as you stick a crystal oscillator to the unit. Note that it might be impossible in low-pin number units.

From my experience the RC oscillator is rather unstable as I measured its frequency to drift by quite a non-negligible amount. The drift increases with temperature. If you don't need time accuracy it's good enough. But if timing accuracy is critical, like in serial communications such as high-speed RS232 or CAN, an external (crystal) oscillator is recommended.

As you read in the data sheet, the frequency of the internal oscillator can be adjusted in steps. This is achieved indeed through the OSCCAL register. You may be limited by the internal PLL though (which the internal oscillator also feeds, depending on how you set the fuses) so the frequency adjustment that can be made is also limited. Refer to the data sheet for the exact limitations.

As Chris Stratton explained the oscillator frequency is trimmed in an analogue way.

Comment: You seem to be misreading the data sheet and mixing up some different concepts.  The Calibrated RC oscillator *does not* incorporate a PLL, and what the OSCCAL register sets is "analog" behavior, not precise divisor steps.  There is a PLL, but that is driven *by* the RC oscillator and used to generate the fast peripheral clock.

Comment: I was mainly interested in the graph displaying oscillator frequency vs. OSCCAL value on page 194 on the datasheet. I noticed that the RC oscillator appears to have a wide range of up to nearly 16MHz. Am I reading that right? I'm mainly wondering about how this is achieved at a hardware level... That's why Im looking for some hardware recommendations about a piece of hardware to order that is most similar to the RC oscillator in the attiny85.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I was interpreting the data sheet in fact as to my understanding setting such steps required another, internal PLL. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I don't really have a practical application for it ATM; just want to mess around with it.

Comment: What happens with the PLL is that if you keep turning up the frequency of the RC oscillator, the PLL's oscillator will top out somewhere around 80 MHz and stop being able to lock to the intended time 8 multiple of the RC oscillator, at which point the peripheral clock will be free running and not locked to the main clock.